# How to remove System.Windows.Forms dependency from .NET Core 8 app targeting a Windows platform?

Tags: winforms, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core app (implementing REST APIs) built with .NET 8 and targeting a Windows platform (need to target Windows because it uses `System.DirectoryServices` which requires Windows). The app does not use Windows Forms explicitly or implicitly (no packages have dependencies on Windows Forms). But for some reason it still requires `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Windows.Forms.Primitives`. I added the `UseWindowsForms` setting to the project file but it did not help:

```
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<UseWindowsForms>false</UseWindowsForms>
```

Is there any way to have a .NET Core app built for a Windows platform to not require Windows Forms? I'm using Visual Studio 2022, if it matters.

Comment: Did you check whether something is using IServiceProvider / IComponent / Component directly, and, for some reason, the automatic source package detection determined that the best fit was the `System.ComponentModel` namespace, member of `System.Windows.Forms.Primitives` (which includes the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace for file dialogs / custom places etc.) -- Do you see, in the Dependencies group, the `Microsoft.WindowDesktop.App.[...]` sub-group? - A .NET Core app, no matter if the target is `net8.0-windows`, doesn't require/use Windows.Forms at all

Comment: @AlekDavis: What is your project Sdk?

Comment: @Jimi: I do not see IServiceProvider/IComponent/Component anywhere. There is no Microsoft.WindowsDesktop under dependencies. The project has no UI (other than Swagger). Under Dependencies: under Frameworks, there's System.Windows and under Analyzer, there are System.Windows.Forms.Analyzer ad System.Windows.Forms.Analyzers.CSharp-System.Windows.Forms.Generators.ApplicationConfigurationGenerator. Not sure what this one does.

Comment: @Jackdaw: I'm not sure how to check the SDK. I'm using VS 2022 with .NET 8 and whatever they come with by default.

Comment: @AlekDavis: 1) The project SDK should be defined in the first line of the _jour-project.proj_ file. 2) How do you determine that your project has `System.Windows.Forms` dependency when you set `<UseWindowsForms>false</UseWindowsForms>`?

Comment: @Jackdaw: 1) `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` 2) The project has `System.Windows.Forms` dependency because the CI/CD build pipeline breaks with the error message saying that the assembly is missing (and if I bypass the build error, the app fails to start with the same error message). I have no problem building or running the app locally on my dev system and I can see that both the `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Windows.Forms.Primitives` assemblies are loaded in the app domain.

Comment: Very strange, but seems like some component in your project references to the `System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: If you don't have a dependency on Windows.Desktop stuff, then a third party component may be using that assembly. Some reporting service maybe? Something uses message boxes, other forms of dialogs... Can the `AppDomain.AssemblyLoad` event help in determining when this happens?

Comment: @Jackdaw No, no components are using System.Windows.Forms. The dependency appears when I change the platform from (None) to Windows. If I create an empty .NET Core app project and set the platform to Window, the System.Windows.Forms dependency will apear. Once I reset it to (None), it will go away, so no, it's not a fault of any package dependency.

Comment: @Jimi See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/4468, this is a bug introduced in a later version of the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` package. There are [several workarounds](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/4468#issuecomment-1998589287) that can be used. I chose to change the `Windows` OS setting back to `(None)` and disable the `CA1416` warning via the following line in the `.editorconfig` file:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1416.severity = none
```

The warning just says that the `System.DirectoryServices` APIs only work on Windows, but as long as the app is deployed on a Windows system, it shopuld be fine.